# Button is enabled only when the other button was clicked wpf datagrid

Tags: wpf, button, datagrid, isenabled

I have 2 buttons :

In my view MainView.xaml

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <Button Name="wec" Height="50" Content="Podgląd" Margin="15 15 15 0" Command="{Binding ViewCommand}"/>
                <Button Height="50" Content="Drukuj" Margin="15 15 15 0"  Command="{Binding ElementName=pv, Path=PrintCommand}">
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>
            <local:PrintPreview Grid.Row="4" x:Name="pv" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" PrintingClass="{Binding Model.PrintingClass, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" PrintModel="{Binding Model.PrintingModel, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

My first button - command make some view how document will be print.
Second button - command print this document and below code from PrintPreview.xaml.cs

```
private DelegateCommand printCommand;
    public DelegateCommand PrintCommand
    {
        get
        {

            if (printCommand == null)
                printCommand = new DelegateCommand(print);
            return printCommand;
        }
        set
        {
            if (printCommand != value)
            {
                printCommand = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public bool IsFirstButtonClicked { get; set; }

    private bool PrintCommandCanExecute(object unused)
    {
        return this.IsFirstButtonClicked;
    }

 private void print(object x)
    {
        setPageSettings();
        WB.Print();
    }
```

This is not entirely but I hope that will be enough to solve the solution :)

I tried but I can't do this, meaning: I want to second button be active only when the first button will be clicked. Do you have any easy ideas to do this?

Answer (score 0):

First, create a bool property so you know when you clicked your first button, lets call it IsFirstButtonClicked.

In your Print command you should add a CommandCanExecute like:

```
private bool SecondCommandCanExecute(object unused)
 {
   return this.IsFirstButtonClicked;
 }
```

when you click your first button you set your IsFirstButtonClicked (bool property) to true and raise your PrintCommandCanExecute.

---

I guess you have a ICommand FirstCommand. You should create a class like this:

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
private Action<object> _action;
private Func<bool> _func;  

public RelayCommand(Action<object> action,Func<bool> func)
{
    _action = action;
    _func = func;
}

public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
{
    if(CanExecuteChanged!=null)
        CanExecuteChanged(this,new EventArgs());
}

#region ICommand Members

public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
{
    if (_func != null)
       return _func();
    return true;
}



public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

public void Execute(object parameter)
{
    _action(parameter);
}

#endregion
}
```

Now your SecondCommand should be a RelayCommand like this:

```
RelayCommand SecondCommand = new RelayCommand(yourCommandExecute, this.SecondCommandCanExecute)
```

Now when you click your FirstButton, set IsFirstButtonClicked to true and then call SecondCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();

Let me know if it helped you.

Comment: I don't know if I understand well enough: I add a bool property and next I add comman can execute. And what about buttons? I presume that I have to put somehow this commandcanexecute to run this ?

Comment: Edit your OP with your command code and I will update my answer to clarify it :)

Comment: in the same time I edit my OP :) but thank you very much

Comment: Change this public bool IsFirstButtonClicked {get; set;} to this -> private bool IsFirstButtonClicked; And when you click your first button set IsFirstButtonClicked to true and then do this SecondCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged() (now I think you called it PrintView)